# Creating an "abstract schema" in Apache AVRO

Tags: avro

I have a chain of microservices that send AVRO serialized objects to each other in topics.

I want to create a monitoring infrastructure that will log all objects that are being sent in the program.

To implement such infrastructure I need my monitoring process to be able to generically subscribe to each topic, and read common attributes of all objects (e.g. Transaction ID).

The problem is that every object is serialized with different schema, and if I will use this naive implementation of AVRO, my monitoring process will have to use different schema for each topic it is subscribed to (therefore it'll not be generic).

I thought about making one general object that contains the "generic fields", and in addition a Union that contains all types of the project, like this:

```
record Record{
  long transactionId;
  union { null, ObjectA, ObjectB} nestedObject;
}
\\ ...ObjectA and ObjectB definition
```

I think that this will work, but I have 3 problems with this solutions:

1. I'll have to update the "mother-schema" every time that I add an object to the project.
2. All Objects will need to be compiled in all microservices.
3. All Schemas will need to be defined in one file, and therefore to match one version.

Is there a better way of creating a "generic section" for all schemas, that a supervising process will be able to deserialize (without knowing the specific schema)?

Comment: what about use generic records?

Comment: The problem is that generic records are deserialized to GenericRecords (and not to my objects), therefore they disallow OOP.

Comment: I don't see the issue based on the problem that you are trying to solve. could you talk about it?

Comment: The issue is that I need a way for a supervising process to subscribe to every topic in my application (I'm using Kafka, I tried to keep this platform-agnostic), and read specific fields that are common for all objects, while keeping my application object-oriented (generic records don't seem object-oriented to me because they are not deserialized to my objects).

Comment: but GenericRecords provide way to access the fields by name, so you should be able to read the fields that are common between the your objects, it seems to be a possible solution.